# Subquery with Ties

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Goal**: Show the ID, title of the books and the pub. Year for the book with the highest sales amount; include ties. Use the total extended cost (quantity * order price) when determining the sales of a book.

**Rules**:

- use subquery only
- no joins
- no union
- only subquery

**Query**:

```
SELECT  book_id,
        title,
        year_publd
FROM bkinfo.books
where book_id =
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES book_id, quantity*order_price as Extended_cost
    from bkorders.order_details
    order by quantity*order_price DESC
    )
;
```

**Error**:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.

The subquery shows the book_id with the highest amount but when running it as a whole, I receive an error. Please explain what I should do.

Comment: Have you tried to add "and" in where condition for each separate columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT book_id, title, year_publd
FROM bkinfo.books
where book_id =
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 book_id
    from bkorders.order_details
    order by quantity*order_price DESC

    )
;
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that you can do this with 'Order by'

Answer (score 2):

```
;with cte as
(
select book_id, quantity*order_price as Extended_cost from bkorders.order_details
order by Extended_cost DESC
)

select top 1 with ties * from cte
```